# Changing status bar color programmatically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, statusbar

I am working for an application that should be compatible with older Android versions, so after getting a lot of research, I got a solution to change the color of status bar with custom action bar.

However now if I am adding any text/edit field (from layout) under the action bar, on execution it is appearing under the action bar... :( due to this I have to add static margin from the top that maybe not a professional way...

I am using following code to display action bar:

```
    // UR create custom action bar
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar);

    // UR change title of action bar
    TextView customActionBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_text);
    customActionBar.setText(R.string.title_activity_view_event);
```

And I am using the following code for changing status bar color:

```
public void setStatusBarColor(View statusBar,int color){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        //status bar height
        int actionBarHeight = getActionBarHeight();
        int statusBarHeight = getStatusBarHeight();

        //action bar height
        statusBar.getLayoutParams().height = actionBarHeight + statusBarHeight;
        statusBar.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
}
/**
 * This function used internally by setStatusBarColor function
 **/
private int getActionBarHeight() {
    int actionBarHeight = 0;
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
        actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    return actionBarHeight;
}
/**
 * This function used internally by setStatusBarColor function
 **/
private int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```